# how to produce a plot using different powers of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have got the following transition matrix.

```
n <-10
A<-matrix(0,n,n)
diag(A[-1,]) <-0.5 
diag(A[,-1]) <-0.5 
A[1,n]<-0.5
A[n,1]<-0.5
```

How can I get a plot like below by producing different powers of A and calculate the 1-norms?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I only managed to get the matrix, but have no idea how to produce different powers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the power of a matrix, you can use the `expm` package or the `matrixcalc` package:

```
A <- toeplitz(c(1,2,3)) # a square matrix
A
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    2    1    2
# [3,]    3    2    1

library(expm)
A %^% 2
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   14   10   10
# [2,]   10    9   10
# [3,]   10   10   14

library(matrixcalc)
matrix.power(A, 2)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   14   10   10
# [2,]   10    9   10
# [3,]   10   10   14
```

For the plot:

```
powers <- 0:8
Apowers <- lapply(powers, function(k) A %^% k)
norms <- sapply(Apowers, norm, type = "1")

plot(powers, norms)
```